# Call parent function from subproject

Tags: groovy, gradle

Is there way in Gradle how to call parent function from subproject?
If I have parent project and function defined as:

```
def testMethod() {
    println("TestMethod called from directory ${project.projectDir}")
}
```

and subproject as:

```
task subTest << {
    println("I'm subTest task from ${project.projectDir}")
    testMethod()
}
```

calling this from commandline results in:

```
Could not find method testMethod() for arguments [] on root project 'subsys1'
```

Comment: it works for me:

$ gradle subTest
:web-shop-war:subTest
I'm subTest task from C:\...\web-shop\web-shop-war
TestMethod called from directory C:\...\web-shop

have you defined your subproject as a subproject in settings.gradle?

Comment: Yes, it works when you invoke it from root project directory as 
>gradle subsys1:subTest
But I need to invoke
>gradle subTest 
// from subsys1 directory, then it's somehow problem to construct project tree for Gradle. It's opposite tree direction when you invoke task from subproject. I would need to set parent project into subsystem settings.gradle so it knows, where to look for testMethod()

Comment: What do you mean with "in subsystem settings.gradle"? Gradle only supports one settings.gradle for the entire project tree, which is located in the root project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Could not find method testMethod() for arguments [] on root project 'subsys1'
```

Means that Gradle thinks that `subsy1` is the root project, whereas your parent project should be the root project. This means that you have more than 1 settings.gradle, and it thinks that subsys1 is the start of the project hierarchy. There should only be 1 `settings.gradle` file, which should reside in the root project. There you configure each of the subprojects. They don't get their own `settings.gradle` files.

Comment: Basically, you're right. However I have 3-level hierarchy consisting of system/subsystem/module. I do realize, that if I run gradle from system level, it uses top level settings.gradle to configure subprojects. But I also need to support some operations on subsystem level, so there additional settings.gradle which configures modules. As I describe in another comment, I did realize that my testMethod() was not found due to 'inverted' project hierarchy assembled when running build from subsystem. Subsystem itself was root project which caused mentioned problems.

Comment: The top level settings.gradle can also configure lower level (modules) projects... Just refer to them using the correct path (:subsystem:module)